# How can I run shell exec - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to run the shell code when the Laravel application runs.
I created a provider and registered the first provider

```
    'providers' => [
        App\Providers\RunServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
        */
          ....
```

And I put this code in boot

```
 public function boot()
    {
        if (!is_writable(storage_path()) || !is_writable(base_path('bootstrap/cache'))) {
            shell_exec('sudo chown -R $USER:www-data ./storage/');
            shell_exec('sudo chown -R $USER:www-data ./bootstrap/cache/');

            shell_exec("chmod -R 775 ./storage/");
            shell_exec("chmod -R 775 ./bootstrap/cache/");
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work, is the code correct? Is the storage & bootstrap path correct?

Is there a way to give permissions to folders?

Comment: Does the user running the web server have permission to run `sudo` without being prompted for a password?

Comment: It's asking me for a password ,can it be ignored for this process only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute sudo command without password, you should setup sudo before.
Pls have a look here: https://linuxhandbook.com/sudo-without-password/

But in general, it's a bad practice to do things like that, especially on the app boot. Why do you need to check & update permissions on every request? Normally the permissions are not changing so often. Usually such things can be done once during the deploy and automated.